# How do you run a script in CodeSandBox?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, codesandbox

I have a simple app.js file in codesandbox.

Normally in VSCode with nodejs installed, I can just run `node app` and the file runs

How can I do the same on codesandbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it auto starts with nodemon so you don't have to start a app